# Add country code in all routes

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Is it possible to add `/in` after origin of URL. Right now URL is `xxx.com/home/index` and want it like `xxx.com/in/home/index`. 
It is change based on country, For India `/in`, For US `/us` etc.

I add scope in routes,

```
scope ":country_code" do
  root 'home#index'
  get 'page/about'
end
```

How can I navigate root path and have to change all code to change path? 
Is there any other solution?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a list of all supported countries in your application - in a constant perhaps? How do you want to use this information in your application?

Comment: Don't want to use country_code in application. Just add it in URL, when i select country from dropdown, i want it in all URL based on country selection. 
If I select US then URL like 1. /us/home/index, 2. /us/users
If I select Canada URL like 1. /ca/home/index, 2. /ca/users

Comment: If you do not want to use the country code in your application then why add it to the URL in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. As per your requirement you need to us `country_code` as we use for `id` in **routes**.

First of all, You need to make a **root** `action` in a `controller` like:

```
root_to "welcome#index"
```

Then we need to define a route something like:

```
xyz/:country_code/member_action => "welcome#search", as: "my_action"
```

Now when any request will received at `root_path` in `index` action of `WelcomeController`, we will check the request IP country details.

You can use https://ipinfodb.com/api  to get the country details of request IP

And finally after getting the `country_code`, redirect the request to the next action path from here like: `redirect_to my_action_path("IN")`

Comment: yes, it is possible in this way. But then I need to change every path in code. I have to add country_code in all path. Is there any other way to add it in URL with minimal changes in code?

Comment: You will also need to change the urls when you will use  "xxx.com/in/home/index" at the place of xxx.com/home/index. I will say put all of your routes as member routes then may be it will helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can define all routes inside dynamic namespace will use normal routes if you pass `module: false` like so:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  ['us','uk','in'].each do |country_code|
    namespace country_code.to_sym, module: false do
      resources :users

      root 'home#index'
      get 'page/about'
    end
  end
```